# How to retrieve the stock price in specific date in the excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have tried using the stockhistory formula `(=STOCKHISTORY(I8,G8, ,0,0,1))` to get the stock price of a certain ticker on a specific day, but the box that comes out has 2x2 information, which is not what I need. I just need the stock price for that day. I have searched online and looked at many sources, but I cannot find a solution.

The only formula I have found is the one shown in the picture. Using this formula works for some tickers, but not for all NASDAQ tickers. I am not sure how to fix this.

The screenshot of the error I encountered:
[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See [STOCKHISTORY function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stockhistory-function-1ac8b5b3-5f62-4d94-8ab8-7504ec7239a8)  In particular review the options for **`headers`** as well  as **`property0 - property5`**

Comment: Welcome Thomas! Please take some time to read the introduction to SuperUser
https://superuser.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

You merely use the `INDEX` function to return the single item you wish.

For example, to return just the closing price of IBM on 4-Jan-2023, you would use something like:

```
=INDEX(STOCKHISTORY("IBM", "2023/1/4"),2,2)
```

Obviously, you can replace the constants with cell references.

Comment: +1 The OP must make sure that the date is in the correct regional format as they might get a `#VALUE` error that the start date is in the future.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio This is just an example of the INDEX function. In his presented information, he is accessing the date value using a cell reference. I should probably have used an unambiguous date string in the example.  I will change it. Tks

Answer (score 0):

I seldom work with Data Types so I have no routine experience with the "headliner" feature here and there may be something subtle there that eludes me.

However, the formula works for me when I enter it. It works on the Data Type directly and it works when I use a concatenation formula to form the "Stock Market: Stock Ticker" strings you have. It also works on strictly text (typed) versions.

There is one thing though, not related to the "headliner" here, the Data Types present. That is the dates being used. They work fine for me, but then, I entered them as dates. And even when I format them as Text, Excel realizes they are to be used here as dates and has no difficulty whatever.

But the column header (column G) specifies, presumably to the worker-bee entering data, the format of the information be "MM-DD"... yet the data is actually left-justified, a very frequent "sure-fire" sign that an entry is actually text. And the data present looks incredibly different from the formatting of the rest of the data.

I have to conclude that most likely the data was obtained from somewhere, where not being too important to us, and was in text form, then certainly pasted in as Text.

So the formula you show is not being given an actual date, nor something Excel is trying to use as a date. Hence the formula's failure and the particular error you are getting.

The symbol (circled "?") in row 2 is interesting as it would suggest Excel having an inability to match it up, but it does not happen to me so... can't help much there, but then you don't bring that up either.

The related issue you mentioned, that of the data return being a 2x2 return I flat out cannot reproduce using the data you are trying to collect. I can get a 1x2 return seeking other data from the Data Type, and imagine other of the included information could yield a 2x2 return, but then, not with what you are saying you are asking it for.

That said, there is an incredibly easy way to deal with an "NxM" return:  use `INDEX` to strip out the single piece of data you want. I sought until I got the 1x2 return so that I could directly test using it on a Data Type's return and it worked like a champ.

So make the dates actual dates, and use `INDEX` on multi-item returns to extract the piece of them you need.

Weirdly, people don't think of `INDEX` in this way but a red-headed cousin is still a cousin.

By the way, just reformatting the dates might lead you to think I'm completely off-base as often you do such a thing and Excel does not immediately DO its part. You then have to do one or another "Coercion" techniques to push Excel into doing so. Easiest way? Copy the pasted data to an empty page using `Paste|Special|Values` and then, when seeing them displayed as real dates, copy and paste back to column G. Otherwise, you definitely risk being fooled by Excel not actually acting upon your formatting change and thinking I probably am writing from Wrongtown, USA.

Side note:  I got a lot of `#BUSY` errors when pasting formulas. If typing, then pressing Enter, I got immediate happiness. Go to a pasted patch and press F2, then Enter, immediate happiness. One bypass for that was to use a range instead of the "G8" and "I8" addressing. Then press Enter and instead of one good cell, I had the column all good, no "Busy signals."

I believe the problem hasn't anything at all to do with the Data Types, or the formula.

Comment: Could I suggest that you could improve your answer by cutting out the waffle and stick to the relevant points.  I can not tell if you have answered the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).